# What is the safe rpm limit for a solid steel wheel

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What is the safe rpm limit for a solid mild steel wheel. Outside diameter equals 16.564” thickness equals 3.862”  Inside dia. Is 2.56”. The wheel is supported by a tapered hub onto a shaft. The hub does exert force outward but I don’t know how to calculate that.
I’m building an inertia Dyno.
Or accelerometer.

Comment: You could compare centripetal stresses against the material tensile strength to set an upper limit. It's going to be lower than that though since no material is perfectly uniform and it isn't going to be perfectly balanced. What it can really handle is going to come down to these non-idealities.

Comment: @Jeff Huddlett: If possible, consider composite flywheels for high safe rpm. A lot of literature is available by googling.

Comment: I already have the wheel as described. Just trying to avoid a catastrophic failure .

Answer (score 1):

For a start calculate per:

[Rotating Disk with hole](https://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/stresses_in_rotating_disks_15285.htm)

But it is possible to vary cross-section as bell curve profile to increase speed and reduce  weight.